# How to get the selected value in list view?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I have a little problem here..

I have create form and there are arrays for year and month using list view.

My conditions is if year or month not selected the pop-up will tell you to re-fill the form.

The problem is, the if statement was not correct.

How actually to call value  that had been selected in the list view?

```
public class card extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner spinnerOsversions;


 Spinner spinnerOsversions2;

Button btnCtlr;

 private String[] Month = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};   
 private String[] Year = { "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019","2020" , "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024","2025" };

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.card);


         spinnerOsversions = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.osversions);
         spinnerOsversions2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.osversions2);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Month);
                    adapter_state
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                  spinnerOsversions.setAdapter(adapter_state);
                  spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


                  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Year);
                            adapter_state2
                            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                          spinnerOsversions2.setAdapter(adapter_state2);
                          spinnerOsversions2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



        btnCtlr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);            
        btnCtlr.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

    }
    public void onItemSelected1(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
               long id) {
         spinnerOsversions.setSelection(position);
          String selState = (String) spinnerOsversions.getSelectedItem();


             }

    public void onItemSelected2(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
               long id) {
         spinnerOsversions2.setSelection(position);
          String selState = (String) spinnerOsversions2.getSelectedItem();



             }



    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view) {

if((spinnerOsversions2.getSelectedItem().toString() == null) || ((spinnerOsversions.getSelectedItem().toString() == null))){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder2=new AlertDialog.Builder(card.this);
                 builder2.setMessage("Please fill in all the information.");
                  builder2.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                          Intent intObj2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),card.class);
                            startActivity(intObj2);


                       }
                  });
                  AlertDialog dialog = builder2.create();
                  dialog.show();

            }

            else{
            Intent intObj = new Intent(card.this,
                    tq.class);

            startActivity(intObj);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the month and year in the onclick of the listview?

Comment: Where's the listview? I couldn't find it anywhere in the code. Please point out (if it is there)

Comment: @Aniruddha already update my code.

Comment: @ZInj ..already try to do this, but it doesn't work.String month = spinnerOsversions.getSelectedItem().toString();
    
    String year = spinnerOsversions2.getSelectedItem().toString();